# Using FlatWorm to Write a Flat File

Tags: java, flat-file

Good Afternoon in my timezone.

In my current web project, i have to write a flat file(with some fixed rules).After a web research i found a library which is called FlatWorm that help's me write flat files in a easy way.The problem is that there is a lack of information regarding the XML definition file.I have the FlatWorm API, but there is nothing related with the XML definition file and all the tags and attributes that build it.

Anyone that use and knows about this framework can give me a clue ?

With best regards.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I would start by [RTFMing](http://flatworm.sourceforge.net/). There appears to be a fair amount of information on there that should get you kick started, including some examples you could start by modifying.

Google suggests some other examples, such as, http://javaconfessions.com/2009/04/writing-flat-files-in-java-with.html and http://andreamoz.blogspot.com/2010/12/meet-flatworm.html

Unfortunately the DTD for the XML descriptor either never existed, or at least doesn't any more. If needed, I would look through the XML parsing source to see what the flatworm library actually makes use of.

Comment: First of all , tanks for your reply :)
I already saw the above examples pages.Looking in the XML Parser source is an alternative. Thanks anyway

Comment: Unless we know specifics about what you're trying to do and what isn't working, it's pretty hard to be more specific in any answer!

Comment: hi, i cannot find this library anymore i mean my mvn install cannot find that library. do you know it still exist ?